# How to Bind to Properties of ContentControl Content Object

Tags: wpf, binding, code-behind, contentcontrol

I am working with WPF legacy code that is not MVVM :-(

I have the following declaration in my main window (AppWindow.xaml):

```
                    <ContentControl x:Name="AppView" Content="{Binding UserControlView}"/>
```

In the AppWindow.xaml.cs file (code-behind), UserControlView is defined as:

```
    private object _userControlView;
    public object UserControlView
    {
        get { return _userControlView; }

        set
        {
            _userControlView= value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

I can assign one of a number of different user controls to UserControlView, so that it is displayed in the ContentControl area. All user control logic is in its code-behind file.  Each of the user controls has a common set of three properties (PropA, PropB and PropC) that I would like to bind to in the AppWindow.xaml file.

Is there a way that I can bind to PropA, PropB and PropC in the AppWindow.xaml file declarations?

Comment: `"{Binding Path=UserControlView.PropA}"` will work

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks so much!

Comment: I thought there would be an issue since UserControlView was of type object ... but I later learned "Binding framework automatically converts the source object to relevant type and uses the bound property value"